# why Find-Minimum operation in priority queue implemented in unsorted array take only complexity = O(1) ? <steven skiena's the algorithm design manual>

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue

In steven skiena's the algorithm design manual (page 85),

The author show in a table that priority queue implemented in unsorted array only take O(1) for both insertion and find minimum operation.
[image: priority queue analysis - steven skiena's the algorithm design manual]

For my understanding unsorted array wasn't able get the minimum item in O(1) , because it has to search through the whole array to get the minimum.

is there any details i missed out in priority queue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (mostly) written there under the table:

> The trick is using an extra variable to store a pointer/index to the minimum ...

Presumably, the next word is "value", meaning it's a simple `O(1)` dereference to get the minimum.

When inserting an item, you just append it to the end and, if it's less than the current minimum, update that pointer/index. That means `O(1)` for the insert.

The only "expensive" operation is then delete-minimum. You know *where* it is due to the pointer/index but it will take `O(n)` operations to shuffle the array elements beyond it down one.

And, since the cost is already `O(n)`, you may as well take the opportunity to search the array for the new minimum and store its position in the pointer/index.

---

The pseudo-code for those operations be something along the lines of (first up, initialisation and insertion, and assuming zero-based indexes):

```
class prioQ:
    array = []      # Empty queue.
    lowIndex = 0    # Index of lowest value (for non-empty queue).

    def insert(item):
        # Add to end, quick calc if array empty beforehand.

        array.append(item)
        if len(array) == 1:
            lowIndex = 0
            return

        # Adjust low-index only if inserted value smaller than current.

        if array[lowIndex] > item:
            lowIndex = len(array) - 1
```

Then a function to find the actual minimum value:

```
    def findMin():
        # Empty array means no minimum. Otherwise, return minimum.

        if len(array) == 0: return None
        return array[lowIndex]
```

And, finally, to extract the minimum value (remove it from the queue and return it):

```
    def extractMin():
        # Empty array means no minimum. Otherwise save lowest value.

        if len(array) == 0: return None
        retVal = array[lowIndex]

        # Shuffle down all following elements to delete lowest one

        for index = lowIndex to len(array) - 2 inclusive:
            array[index] = array[index + 1]

        # Remove final element (it's already been shuffled).

        delete array[len(array) - 1]

        # Find lowest element and store.

        if len(array) > 0:
            lowIndex = len(array) - 1
            for index = len(array) - 2 to 0 inclusive:
                if array[index] <= array[lowIndex]:
                    lowIndex = index

        # Return saved value.

        return retVal
```

As an aside, the two loops in the `extractMin` function *could* be combined in to one for efficiency. I've left it as two separate loops for readability.

---

One thing you should keep in mind, there are actually variations of the priority queue that preserve insertion order (within a priority level) and variations that do not care about that order.

For the latter case, you don't have to shuffle all the elements to remove an extracted one, you can simply move the last one in the array over the extracted one. This may result in some time savings if you don't actually *need* to preserve insertion order - you still have to *scan* the entire array looking for the new highest-priority item but at least the number of shuffle assignments will be reduced.

Comment: But there's no reason to move everything beyond the minimum element up one in the array. Just take the last active item in the array and put it into the empty position. The removal operation is still O(n), of course, but you don't have the expense of moving all those items.

Comment: @Jim, that would work okay in the case where the sort order uses the entire structure making up each item. However, in the case where you have (for example) an integer priority and string payload, you can't just grab the last item and move it since it may change the order within a priority level. Say you have an array of `nX` items where `n` is the priority and `X` is the payload. If you start with `[1A, 2B, 1C, 1D]` and you remove `2B` by just overwriting it with `1D`, you end up with the priority `1` items in a *new* order: `[1A, 1D, 1C]`. Shuffling would preserve the order within priority.

Comment: The question specifically says "unsorted array," so moving things around in the array won't affect the complexity or the correctness. You still have to do a full scan of the array to find the smallest item the next time the minimum is retrieved. After all, `1F` might be inserted *before* `1E`.

Comment: Jim, I believe unsorted in this sense means unsorted by *priority.* It's still sorted by insertion order by virtue of the fact you're tacking things on at the end. While the "queue" bit could be read as queuing priority levels with order within a priority not being of concern, the vast majority of priority queues will preserve order within the priority as well.

Comment: And it makes no difference whether 1F is inserted before 1E since we're sorting within priority on the insertion order, not the payload key. If you insert `1F` then `1E`, `[1F, 1E]` is the *correct* result.

Comment: "The vast majority of priority queues will preserve order within the priority as well." Certainly no heap-based priority queue will do that unless the caller specifically writes a comparison to implement such functionality. There's no contract in the C++, Java, or Python priority queue implementations that says items with equal priority will be returned in the order in which they were inserted.

Comment: @Jim, I stand corrected. It appears that there are indeed quite a few non-FIFO-within-priority priority queues. I don't really consider those queues myself since they lose the basic property of a queue, the processing in order (other than priority preferences). I think I would rather call them priority bags :-) I'll incorporate the comments in to the answer.

Comment: I agree that it's contrary to what one would expect, given that "queue" in other contexts implies FIFO. Or perhaps I've been mistaken all this time assuming that "FIFO queue" was redundant? Whatever the case, the assumption that priority queues are FIFO within priority has tripped up more than just you and me.

Answer (score 0):

@paxdiablo's answer gives the scheme referred to in the book. Another way to achieve the same complexity is to always store the minimum at the first index in the array:

- To insert `x` in O(1) time, either insert it at the end (if it is bigger than the current minimum), or copy the current minimum to the end and then store `x` at index 0.
- To query the minimum in O(1) time, return the value at index 0.
- To delete the minimum in O(*n*) time, search for the new minimum from index 1 onwards, write it at index 0, then "fill in the gap" by swapping the element at the last index to where the new minimum used to be.